# Keep non form related data (like dropdown options) in controller's post action

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

Controller:

```
public ActionResult New()
{
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.AllUsers = **Run a Database Query to get all users**
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("New", "Card", FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "id", "cardForm" } }))
{
    **Among other form fields***
    <div class="control-group">
        label class="control-label LabelStyle">
            Assigned To
        </label>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AssignedToIds, Model.AllProjectUsersList.ToSelectList(u => u.Id.ToString(), u => u.Text, u => u.Selected ), new { @class = "chosen", multiple = "multiple"})
        </div>
    </div>
}
<script>
    var cardForm = $('#cardForm');
    cardForm.submit();
</script>
```

Controller (Post Action):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(CardFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The problem is, if the `ModelState` is Invalid, and I return the `View` with the `viewModel`, `AllProjectUsersList` is null. Hence, an exception occurs when building the view. I can, of course, fix this by running the database query again and populating `AllProjectUsersList`.

Is there any way that I can keep the previously populated `AllProjectUsersList` or avoid the database query some other way?

Comment: If you have property implemented client side validation, then it would be rare that `ModelState` will be invalid.Unless you were to create an input for each `SelectListItem` in the view so it posts back (which would be crazy) then no. But you can always cache the data on the server

Comment: I have implemented a custom `Validator` for one of the properties. Its validation happens on the server side, instead of client side. Is this wrong? Can its validation happen on the client side (like `RequiredAttribute`)?

Comment: Your validation attribute needs to implement `IClientValidatable` and you need to write the scripts to add the rules to the `$.validator`. [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) is a good guide to creating validation attrbutes for both client and server side validation.

Comment: Oh! I had really just assumed custom validators will work only on the server side. Thank you. Also, will look at caching the dropdown options on the server.